# Determining a tricky limit

Tags: calculus, limits

What is the limit of

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\log n}{n^\delta}$$

where $\delta > 0$?

Comment: $0{}{}{}{}{}{}$.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint 1:** Substituting $n\mapsto n^{1/\delta}$ yields
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log(n)}{n^\delta}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1\delta\frac{\log(n)}{n}
$$
**Hint 2:** Using the inequality for all real $x$
$$
1+x\le e^x
$$
Substitute $x\mapsto x/2$ and square to get
$$
\left(1+\frac x2\right)^2\le e^x
$$
which says
$$
\frac x{e^x}\le\frac4{2+x}
$$
From this, we can deduce that
$$
\frac{\log(n)}{n}\le\frac4{2+\log(n)}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Write: $n^a = e^{a\ln n} > 1 + a\ln n + (a \ln n)^{\frac{2}{2!}}$. Then:
$\frac{\ln n}{n^a} < \frac{1}{a\ln n} \to 0$.
So the answer is: $0$ (zero)

Answer (score 0):

$\ln(n)$ grows slower than linear so whatever is $n$ the denumerator grows faster than the numerator and the limit is 0

Comment: Without some calculus it isn't obvious, I suppose, that logarithm grows slower than, for example, $n^{10^{-100000}}$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\ln n}{n^\delta} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n \cdot \delta n^{\delta - 1}} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{\delta n^\delta} = 0$$

where in the first passage we used Hopital rule